# Determining the Orthonormal Basis for the Column Space of a Matrix using SVD

Tags: matlab, svd

I have a matrix `A = [1 1 2; 2 1 3; 3 1 4; 4 1 5];` with rank of 2. I want to find the orthonormal basis of the column space of this matrix using Singular Value Decomposition (SVD):

```matlab
[U S V] = svd(A);
```

Now, since the rank is 2, the first 2 columns of the left singular vector matrix, `U` should provide me the orthonormal basis vectors for the column space of matrix `A`. But, using `rref(A)` and calculating the column space gives me these orthonormal basis vectors:
`[0.1825, 0.36514, 0.5477, 0.7303]` and `[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]` which is not the same as the first 2 column vectors of `U`.

How can I obtain the basis vectors using `svd()`?

Comment: Semicolons are used to create new rows. I think you need `A = [1 1 2; 2 1 3; 3 1 4; 4 1 5]`.

Comment: There should exist an infinite number of different orthonormal bases for any space, shouldn't there? So I don't see why two algorithms returning two different sets of vectors should be a problem, as long as both sets actually construct orthonormal bases for your column space.

Comment: @MatteoV understood. i'm pretty new to these concepts so got a little confused. thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: @TroyHaskin my bad. i copied it directly from my matlab script so i didnt have to put the semicolons as long as the rows are in the next line of code. im fixing it anyway. thank you. :)

Comment: Simply normalizing the first two columns of `A` does not produce a set of orthonormal vectors (i.e., the two vectors you provided do not have a zero inner product). The vectors must also be orthogonalized against a chosen vector (using a method like [Gram–Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)). This will likely still differ from the SVD, however, since that method scales and rotates its basis vectors without affecting the columnspace.

Answer (score -1):

```
a=sym(y);
display(a);
rank(a);
display(rank(a));
at=transpose(a);
nullspace = null(a);
display(nullspace);
%Display the column space,row space and null space of a matrix
a=[1 1 2; 2 1 3; 3 1 4; 4 1 5];
nullspace = null(a);
display(nullspace);

columnspaceA = colspace(a);
display(columnspaceA);

leftnullspace = null(at);
display(leftnullspace);

rowspaceA = colspace(at);
display(rowspaceA);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Also, how is this supposed to answer the question? This does not calculate a singular value decomposition, nor does it mention why the orthonormal vectors as obtained by the OP aren't the same as those obtained with `svd()`. This just displays a bunch of properties of some matrix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).